# How could I desaturate the image from color to black and white?

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have been working with my code for changing the color of an image but I did not know what to do next in the nested for loop?

Only what I have so far is averaging the Red, Green, and Blue pixel values at each pixel location in the image.

can anyone help/suggest to me what should I do next?

```
#include "desaturate.h" 
void Desaturate(graphics::Image &image) {

  // Returns the width and height of the image.
  int GetWidth();
  int GetHeight();

  // Create variable
  int red;
  int green;
  int blue;

  // Gets the red, green or blue pixel value at an (x, y) pixel location.
  int GetRed(int x, int y);
  int GetGreen(int x, int y);
  int GetBlue(int x, int y);

  // Sets the red, green or blue pixel value at an (x, y) pixel location.
  bool SetRed(int x, int y, int red);
  bool SetGreen(int x, int y, int green);
  bool SetBlue(int x, int y, int blue);

  // Gets the width of the image.
  int width = image.GetWidth();
  // Gets the height of the image.
  int height = image.GetHeight();

  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < height; j++) {
      int average = (red + green + blue) / 3;

      // What should I do next for this part?
    }
  }
```

Comment: Parts of the code seem to have been copy-pasted twice. And much of the code doesn't really make much sense in a function. Please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: What is not clear for you about what to do with the `average` color? For something to appear gray the r, g, and b value of a pixel has to be the same. And with `int average = (red + green + blue) / 3;` you have one way of calculating a possible gray value of the pixel.

Comment: I basically do not get the part when the for loop starts and use it over every pixel in the image and desaturate them one by one

Comment: The value of red, green, and blue values for the pixel at the coordinates `i`, `j`, calculate the average for that pixel and then set the value of red, green, and blue for the pixel at the coordinates `i`, `j`, so that it results in gray.

Comment: So after I calculate the average, I set up like this `image[i][j] = average`?

Comment: Do I need to set the red green and blue in the beginning?

Comment: `image[i][j] = average` no, at least not form the code you show. I mean you have these two comments: `// Gets the red, green or blue pixel value at an (x, y) pixel location.` and `// Sets the red, green or blue pixel value at an (x, y) pixel location.`. So what's wrong with using those functions shown there?

Comment: `Do I need to set the red green and blue in the beginning?` well yes you need to set their values, using those get functions, how else do you want to get the current color of the pixel?

Comment: I see. And I set up like this but it says I'm out of bounds? ```for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
    int r = image.GetRed(i,j);
    int g = image.GetGreen(i, j);
    int b = image.GetBlue(i,j);
    int result = (r + g + b) / 3;
    image.SetRed(i,j,result);
    image.SetGreen(i,j,result);
    image.SetBlue(i,j,result);
  }
}```

Comment: Nevermind I got it. Thank you very much